# Why does getFacesContext() become null

Tags: java, debugging, jsf-2

I have a JSF 2 application running on Jetty 9, Mojarra 2.1 and PrimeFaces 3.3.

In the initial page, I get `NullPointerException`.

I debugged it and found out that `getFacesContext()` inside `getViewMap()` of `javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot` becomes null:

```
public Map<String, Object> getViewMap(boolean create) {
   ...
   viewScope = new ViewMap(getFacesContext().getApplication().getProjectStage());
```

I wonder why might this happen?

Answer (score 1):

static FacesContext getCurrentInstance():
Gets the context for the request that is being handled by the current thread,
or null if the current thread does not handle a request.

Comment: Thank you. So current thread does not handle a request. And why does this happen? The rendering of the page has not yet completed.